# google analytics limit 'Queries per day' of service 'analytics.googleapis.com error without reaching the limit

Tags: google-analytics, google-api, google-analytics-api

I recently get the following error when I try to reach google analytics API :

> Quota exceeded for quota group 'default' and limit 'Queries per day' of service 'analytics.googleapis.com' for consumer 'project_number:XXX'.

I get the error only sometime to time.
According to the documentation the limit is 50.000 calls per day, but when I check my google console API dashboard I never reached this limit (reporting and management services cumulated).

Are the data source to count the limit on google console and and the API different ?

Comment: What happens if you try a different view id?

Comment: I get the same error even if I try to request datas for others views/ properties / GA accounts ids.

Comment: Go to google developer console and manage the google analytics api in your application check what the limit is set to.  someone may have turned down your limit.  However the 50k limit should reset at midnight West cost USA time every day. So i find it strange you would be hitting that unless someone set your quota to 0